# Using is_plugin_active within functions.php

Tags: functions

I'm trying to use `is_plugin_active` within functions.php.

I need to wrap my `useragent_shortcode` function within `is_plugin_active` because when Contact Form 7 gets deactivated, I get a white screen.

I've included `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php` as shown in other WPSE answers because this is outside of admin, but no luck. The shortcode function doesn't run and the raw shortcode is echoed to the page.

Any ideas? Is my code too complex for what I want to do?

***4/16/12 Update: My own answer is below.***

This works in functions.php:

```
 If (in_array( 'contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {


function useragent_shortcode($tag) {

    if ( ! is_array( $tag ) )
        return '';

    $options = (array) $tag['options'];
    foreach ( $options as $option ) {
        if ( preg_match( '%^name:([-0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$%', $option, $matches ) ) {
            $name_att = $matches[1];
        }

          $userAGENT .= $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
     }

     $user_agent = $userAGENT;
     $html = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name_att . '" value="'.$user_agent.'" />';
     return $html;
}
wpcf7_add_shortcode('useragent', 'useragent_shortcode', true);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
     If (in_array( 'contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    function useragent_shortcode($tag) {

        if ( ! is_array( $tag ) )
            return '';

        $options = (array) $tag['options'];
        foreach ( $options as $option ) {
            if ( preg_match( '%^name:([-0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$%', $option, $matches ) ) {
                $name_att = $matches[1];
            }

              $userAGENT .= $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
         }

         $user_agent = $userAGENT;
         $html = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name_att . '" value="'.$user_agent.'" />';
         return $html;
    }
    wpcf7_add_shortcode('useragent', 'useragent_shortcode', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function useragent_shortcode($tag) {

    include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
    if ( is_plugin_active('contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php') ) {

        if ( ! is_array( $tag ) )
            return '';

        $options = (array) $tag['options'];
        foreach ( $options as $option ) {
            if ( preg_match( '%^name:([-0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$%', $option, $matches ) ){
                $name_att = $matches[1];
            }
            $userAGENT .= $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        }

        $user_agent = $userAGENT;
        $html = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name_att . '" value="'.$user_agent.'" />';
        return $html;
    } else {
        //CF7 not found, hence do this
    }
}

wpcf7_add_shortcode('useragent', 'useragent_shortcode', true);
```

I've modified your code a little to move the condition inside the shortcode function itself.

Comment: That's exactly the opposite of what I'm trying to do. `useragent_shortcode` has to be loaded only when the CF7 plugin is active, or else the site whitescreens.